# Grouping results belonging to the same product number into the same record

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

I have a very long query that I have shortened and anonymized so the problem becomes clearer.

Here is an approximation of my query:

```
SELECT subquery1.productNumber,
       subquery1.anotherinfo,
       subquery2.label_a,
       subquery2.label_b,
       subquery2.label_c
FROM (SELECT productNumber,
             anotherinfo
      FROM table1
      WHERE somethingelse = 'limitation') as subquery1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT productNumber,
                  CASE WHEN table2.label = 'H' THEN 'example1'
                       WHEN table2.label = 'I' THEN 'example2' END AS 'label_a',
                  CASE WHEN table2.label = 'J' THEN 'example3'
                       WHEN table2.label = 'K' THEN 'example4' 
                       WHEN table2.label = 'L' THEN 'example5' END AS 'label_b',
                  CASE WHEN table3.label = 'M' THEN 'example6' END AS 'label_c'
           FROM table2
           WHERE label IN ('H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M')) AS subquery2 
       ON subquery2.productNumber = subquery1.productNumber
ORDER BY subquery1.productNumber ASC
```

"*Current Output*":

| ProductNumber | anotherInfo | label_a | label_b | label_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | (correct result) | example1 |  |  |
| 10001 | (corrrect result) |  | example4 |  |
| 10001 | (correct result) |  |  | example6 |
| 10002 | (correct result) | example2 |  |  |
| 10002 | (correct result) |  | example5 |  |
| 10002 | (correct result) |  |  | example6 |
| 10003 | (correct result) | example1 |  |  |
| 10003 | (correct result) |  | example5 |  |

I'd want to have one row for each "*ProductNumber*" with the information for the labels in the same record. I cannot use `GROUP BY` instead of `ORDER BY` because, as soon as I use it, label_b gets recorded earliest in table2, so that information is the only one displayed from that subquery, and the result changes to the following:

| ProductNumber | anotherInfo | label_a | label_b | label_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | (corrrect result) |  | example4 |  |
| 10002 | (correct result) |  | example5 |  |
| 10003 | (correct result) |  | example5 |  |

More subqueries are not a preferred option as the entire thing is already way too big. It should be possible to fuse it via Spreadsheet/Excel, but maybe there is a simple Mysql solution for it I just have not thought about yet.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: check this out: 
[help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: See the tag `[pivot]`

Comment: Thanks! I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply aggregation in the subquery to have a full pivot:

- `MAX` aggregate function will allow you to get the only non-null value
- "*productNumber*" in the `GROUP BY` clause will allow you to do it for each distinct productNumber.

```
SELECT s1.productNumber,
       s1.anotherinfo,
       s1.label_a,
       s1.label_b,
       s1.label_c
FROM      (SELECT productNumber, anotherinfo
           FROM table1
           WHERE somethingelse = 'limitation') as s1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT productNumber,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN table2.label = 'H' THEN 'example1'
                           WHEN table2.label = 'I' THEN 'example2' 
                      END) AS 'label_a',
                  MAX(CASE WHEN table2.label = 'J' THEN 'example3'
                           WHEN table2.label = 'K' THEN 'example4' 
                           WHEN table2.label = 'L' THEN 'example5' 
                      END) AS 'label_b',
                  MAX(CASE WHEN table3.label = 'M' THEN 'example6' 
                      END) AS 'label_c'
           FROM table2
           WHERE label IN ('H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M')
           GROUP BY productNumber) AS s2
       ON s2.productNumber = s1.productNumber
ORDER BY s1.productNumber asc
```

Comment: I got the advise to connect each label via a LEFT JOIN, this solved the problem. I don´t know how to close the question, but thanks to everyone that tried to help.